# Oracle Sql Custom Number Format 999.999,99

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make custom format in oracle sql.

For example I have `125125.25` in column and I want to format like `125.125,25` as expected. Iried

```
select to_char(value,'999.999,99') from ...
```

but it gave me error like

> [Error] Execution (1: 25): ORA-01481: invalid number format model

How can I format like that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
SQL> select to_char(125125.25, '999G990D00', 'nls_numeric_characters=,.') result from dual;

RESULT
-----------
 125.125,25

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes , It helped me. Numbers maybe a million then I added one more 999G as prefix too. Thank you :)